# Why does my iterator foreach loop never enter/execute?

Tags: java, generics, iterator, queue, doubly-linked-list

I have a for-each loop in a method toString() that should iterate through elements in a generic FIFO queue (implemented using doubly linked list data structure) and concatenate the items in the queue onto the string a, which is returned to enqueue() which prints the string, which is a representation of my queue and its contents after an enqueue call. MY question is, why is the for-each not being executed/entered at all?

I tried inserting System.out.print("Hi"); inside the for-each, and it did not print. So I assume some block(s) of code is hindering it from executing properly.

```
// FIFOQueue is implemented using the structure double linked list (DLL)
// Generic, iterable
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.*;
public class FIFOQueueDLL<Item> implements Iterable<Item>{

    private Node first;
    private Node last;
    private int length = 0;

    // is the queue empty?
    public boolean isEmpty(){
        return length == 0;
    }

    private class Node{
    Item item;
    Node next;
    Node previous;
    }

    // add an item
    public void enqueue(Item n){
        Node newnode = new Node();
        newnode.item = n;
        if(isEmpty()){
            last = newnode;
        } else {
            first.previous = newnode;
        }
        newnode.next = first;
        first = newnode;
        length++;
        System.out.println(this);
    }

    // remove and return the least recently added item
    public Item dequeue(){
        if(isEmpty()){
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        }
        Node t = last;
        if(first == last){
            first = null;
        } else {
            last.previous.next = null;
        }
        last = last.previous;
        t.previous = null;
        length--;
        System.out.println(this.toString(););
        return t.item;
    }

    public String toString(){
        String a = "123";
         for(Item item : this){
            a = a + item;
        }
        return a;
    }

    public Iterator<Item> iterator(){
        return new FIFOIterator();
    }

    private class FIFOIterator implements Iterator<Item>{

        // Declare attribute
        Node curr;

        // Set attribute of node curr
        public FIFOIterator(){
            Node curr = first;
            curr.item = first.item;
            curr.next = first.next;
        }

        //private int i = length;
        public boolean hasNext(){
            return curr != null;
        }
        public Item next(){
            Item a = curr.item;
            curr = curr.next;
            return a;
        }
}
    public static void main(String[] args){
        FIFOQueueDLL<Character> c = new FIFOQueueDLL<Character>();
        char b = 'b';
        c.enqueue(b);
        c.enqueue(b);
    }
}
```

```
Expected output: 123b
                 123bb


Actual output: 123
               123
```

Comment: Can you show your class? Does it implement `Iterable`? What does your method `enqueue` do? You omitted exactly the interesting parts

Comment: `this.iterator().hasNext()` returns `false` and you never enter the loop

Comment: @GhostCat If I want to share the whole program, should I edit my post or paste it in a pastebin and share it in the comment section?

Comment: You dont need the **whole** program, but a [mcve]. And as said: what matters here: how you implement the Iterator methods next() and hasNext().

Comment: [Questions seeking debugging help (*"why isn't this code working?"*) must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) See: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @QBrute hello, I have now edited the post to include the class implementing Iterable, and the class implementing Iterator. I would appreciate any help

Comment: @GhostCat  hello, I have now edited the post to include the class implementing Iterable, and the class implementing Iterator. I would appreciate any help

Comment: Besides the fact that you only add a lower case 'b'  twice, your `FIFOIterator` constructor creates a new object `curr` but does not set it to the field of the same class. Thus your field `curr` is `null` and `hasNext` returns `false`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `FIFOIterator` constructor creates a new object curr but does not set it to the field of the same class. Thus your field `curr` is null and `hasNext` returns `false`.

Change

```
// Set attribute of node curr
public FIFOIterator(){
    Node curr = first;
    curr.item = first.item;
    curr.next = first.next;
}
```

to

```
// Set attribute of node curr
public FIFOIterator(){
    this.curr = first;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I debugged this codeblock:

```
public String toString(){
        String a = "123";
         for(Item item : this){
            a = a + item;
        }
        return a;
    }
```

and saw that "this" holds the value of the `String a`. Do you want to change `Item` class to `Character` class instead, and call `toCharArray()` method on `a` instead of using `this`. This is what I am talking about:

```
public String toString(){
     String a = "123";
      for(Character item : a.toCharArray()){
         a = a + item;
     }
     return a;
 }
```

you will get into the loop and be able to append any new character you want. Hope this helps.

Comment: The output that you will get with this will be: "123123", but thats not very relevant to what the TO wants to do. And `this` does not hold the value of `a` it is the representation of the `FIFOQueueDLL` class and thus invokes the `iterator()` method.